# Sorting result options in a Select2 multi-select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using the jQuery plugin **Select2** (v*4.0.3*) on a web app I'm building at work, and I want to sort the results in the results dropdown menu using a custom sorting function, which will sort the results **based on how they match the search term**. This means I need to know the search term within the sorting function itself.

I looked through [the source](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/src/js/select2/results.js#L94-L98) and found that I can add a `sorter` function, but the sorter function only provides the results found by the Select2 plugin, but not the search term used to find them.

When Googling this, I found that version **3.5.3** of Select2 came with a  *[sortResults](http://select2.github.io/select2/#sort_results)* method, which is given the `results`, `container` and the `query`, and thats exactly what I need.

Why was this taken out of the latest version? Kinda weird that the custom result sorting feature actually lost some functionality, as opposed to gaining some.

The sorting I want to apply basically places any "exact" matches on top, then the matches that **start** with the query in the middle, and everything else on bottom, **[Heres a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/joxrjwev/)**.

Is that possible to do in the latest version of Select2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.

It wasn't taken down, the name just changed from `sortResults` to [`sorter`](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api).